# Cancel RosService Call

Tags: rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my program I have a service call when I need to get some data.

if(ros::service:call("service_x", call_x))

This service goes and gets data from a sensor, processes the data, and pubishes the results.

I want to know if there is way that I can cancel or kill this service call if the sensor node crashes or becomes unresponsive.

Thanks All

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211545/cancel-rosservice-call/) by [Benjamin.Nilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/20058/benjamin.nilson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2015-06-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, services do not support timeouts, cancellation or preemption.

If you need that, you should probably take a look at [actionlib](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2